# How would you modify the operation of subtraction to make it commutative?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example, absolute differences are commutative because $|2-3|=|3-2|$. However, I'm wondering how this could be expanded for subtraction with multiple terms.

Comment: How about, for three, $|x-y|+|y-z|+|z-x|$?  With natural extension (all pairs) for more?

Comment: Interesting, that would work.

Comment: @Workaholic: OK, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For three variables, we can use $|x-y|+|y-z|+|z-x|$. There is a natural extension to $n$ variables $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n$. using 
$$\sum_{1\le i\lt j\le n}|x_i-x_j|.$$
What is not clear is whether these extended notions have a use.

Comment: Isn't this just 1-norm of the differences? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm

Comment: Yes, it can be viewed that way.